# How to load css and js

Tags: javascript, css, load

My js script loads the part of page to another page, but css and js doesn't load(.

For example:
Page 1 contains js which load page 2. Page 2 contains something like .
Page 2 loaded to page 1 succesfully, but doesn't have any css or js? which i include.

This is the code which load page:

```
var newdiv = $('<div id="blah"/>');
$('body').append(newdiv);
$('#blah').load('http://paht/to/file.php', function(){...
```

This is the code of loading page:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "http://path/to/file.css">
<div id="id" class="class">
....
</div>
<script src="http://path/to/js.js"></script>
```

P.S. It's work well, if I copy css and js directly instead of `<link href="...">` and `<script src="...">`.
Page 1 include script which I can't change. I just can change page 2. If i write css and js directly - its work fine, but if i try write link on css and js - it's breaks down.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUjmk.jpg

Comment: Load all scripts into page 1 isn't a solution?

Comment: Could you include the code you are using to load Page 2?

Comment: `js script loads the part of page` - there is nothing about loading js or css.

Comment: Please specify the technology you use load another page: is it a framework, or dynamic DOM injection + Ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your files css and js  are not loaded because `load` use `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document.

To load scripts, you should create `<script>` or `<link>` elements yourself in the document's `<head>`.

Try the function `$.getScript();`

```
$('#blah').load('http://paht/to/file.php', function(){
    $.getScript("path of your script js");
    ...
```

And for css file :

```
$('<link/>', {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    type: 'text/css',
    href: 'path_to_the.css'
}).appendTo('head');
```

---

*Reference :*

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Page 1 include script which I can't change. I just can change page 2. If i write css and js directly - its work fine, but if i try write link on css and js - it's breaks down.

Comment: I edited my answer. Your html structure is composed of 2 tags 'head' after the load? (head of page 1 and head of page 2)

Comment: No, page 2 just contain several div's. Page 2 does'n have head.

Comment: I drew a picture. Have a nice day!

Comment: do you like my drawing?

Comment: Yes, I understand your problem, i'm searching a solution because the `load` function doesn't load  js or css files.

Comment: So i found two options. First one: my answer, it modifies the page 1, or append the script into the page 2 after the load (with the same principle).
The second option: write your css and js code directly into page 2.

Comment: Thanks to you, Mister. I understand, that is so simple ot write code directly. I just very much want to know: "Why it's work whed directly and why doesn't work when link???". Please help me! I cant sleep anymore.